# asp.net mvc action result and count question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, reflection

I am working on a plugin based architecture. Its kind of social networking site. 
For a user, I can have pictures, blogs, videos. but they all come from modules.
So, when you visit a user profile, you see tabs, saying pictures, videos and other things.
I have an interface

```
public interface IUserContent
{
    UserContent GetContent(long id);


}
public class UserContent
{
   public int Count {get;set;}
   public string URL {get;set;
   public string Text {get;set;

}
```

So, if a photos module implements   IUserContent
it will look like this

```
public class UserPhotos : IUserContent
{
  public UserContent GetContent(long id)
  {

     return new UserContent { 
               Count = SomeRepository.GetPhotosCountByUser(id), 
               URL =  string.format("/photos/byuser/{0}",id) ,
               Text ="Photos"  };

 }
}
```

This URL is an action method in Photos Controller.

On my profile page i get all the implementations of IUserContent

```
var list =  GetAllOf(IUserContent);
```

and render them using foreach loop as tabs on user profile page.

Now, my question is, is there any better way to do it. I dont want to use URL as string. 
Or any better practise to achieve it.

Regards

Parminder

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Replace `URL = string.format("/photos/byuser/{0}",id)` with:

```
URL = Url.Action("ByUser", "Photo", new { id })
```

If you wish to generate a url whereby your action is called `ByUser` and accepts an `id` as argument and your controller is called `PhotoController`; or use:

```
URL = Url.RouteUrl("PhotosByUser", new { id })
```

If you wish to generate your url derived from a route called `PhotosByUser`.

See: -

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348.aspx and;
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505215.aspx

For further information :)